# Unable to login to Salesforce using SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, c#, wsdl, enterprise-wsdl

I am currently working on a project to interface out .Net Core 3.1 application to Salesforce.   Unfortunately I am not very familiar with Salesforce and their SOAP API.  I have been attempting to find various solutions to log into SF and access the custom objects.
I have downloaded the Enterprise WSDL and made the appropriate changes as discussed in previous posts.  I added the web service to my C# Core 3.1 Console app and attempting to login.  Unfortunately, I have not been successful and I have sent a tremendous amount of time trying to figure this out; so any help is much appreciated.

Here is the code I am currently working on (NOTE:  I am connecting to the test environment of Salesforce):

```csharp
using FSS_SFService;        // Salesforce Web Service
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {

        static string userName = "<<USERNAME>>";
        static string password = "<<PASSWORD>>";
        static string securityToken = "<<TOKEN>>";
        static SoapClient sc;
        static loginResponse lresp;
        static LoginResult lres;
        static LoginScopeHeader lsr = null;
        static string serverUrl;
        static string sessionId;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
            var loginAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/54.0/0DF7A00000004fr");

            sc = new SoapClient(binding, loginAddress);
            Run();
        }

        static async void Run()
        {
            lresp = await SfLogin();
            lres = lresp.result;
            serverUrl = lres.serverUrl;
            sessionId = lres.sessionId;
            Console.WriteLine("Break");
        }

        static async Task<loginResponse> SfLogin() 
        {
            loginResponse lr = await sc.loginAsync(null, userName, password + securityToken);
            return lr;
        }
    }
}
```

When LoginAsync() is executed, the application hangs and then just shuts down.
I notice the SoapClient doesn't appear to be setup correctly when viewing the properties of the object.

I appreciate the help.
Bob

Comment: There's an example in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189927/net-core-2-0-and-async-await-usage

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the example, which my code is based upon.  However it appeared to be missing some information which required additional research on my part.  I ended up adding the synchronous methods from the WSDL because I could not get the async function to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After additional research and changes to the code, I was finally able to connect (I think) to the organization.  Next up...performing a Query.
Here is my updated code for completeness:

```csharp
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
            var loginAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/54.0/"));

            // Establish login
            sc = new SoapClient(binding, loginAddress);
            lres = sc.login(null, userName, password + securityToken);

            // Constitute a query
            SessionHeader header = new SessionHeader();
            header.sessionId = lres.sessionId;

            QueryOptions qopts = new QueryOptions();
            qopts.batchSize = 250;
            qopts.batchSizeSpecified = true;

            string query = "SELECT FirstName,Id,LastName FROM Contact";

            QueryResult qr = null;
            LimitInfo[] li = sc.queryAll(header, qopts, query, out qr);   // Not working

            sc.logout(header);
        }
```